# Java System.out.println()

Tags: java

I understand that **System** is a class, **out** is a field from **System** class of type **PrintStream** (an instance of **PrintStream** class), and println() is a method from **PrintStream**. But I don't get it how does **PrintStream** get instaniated by **out** when **PrintStream** class is in **java.io** package, and java.io is not automatically imported in Java? Am I missing something?

Comment: An `import` statement simply makes it possible for you to use the simple name of a type (or its member), as opposed to the fully qualified type name.

Comment: If you look at the implementation of `System`, you'll find many `import` statements, but those have nothing to do with how you instantiate a type or initialize an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a global, it was instantiated and initialized by the Java runtime. From the Javadoc (emphasis added),

> The "standard" output stream. **This stream is already open and ready to accept output data.**

Comment: So it kinda "locally imports" the neccessery java.io classes during the initialization of the JVM?

Comment: @CuriousGuy Java doesn't use `imports` internally. That's a convenience for the developer. Instead, Java always uses fully qualified class names. You can examine the bytecode of your class(es) with `javap -v` and I think you really are asking about the [Java Classloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader).

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually instantiated by *out*. If you look at the source code, you will see this line:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

and the javadoc says that it "is already open and ready to accept output data."

Here you have a link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: btw, the same goes for `System.err` as well :-)

Comment: Yes, but the type "PrintStream" is a class. So it should be already available for use if it creates variable out of type PrintSteream?

Comment: What I meant by "not actually instantiated" is that *out* is a static member, which means you don't need to create an instance of `System` in the form of `System s = new System(); s.out()`. The class `PrintStream` is, of course, available for use ... although I am not sure what "available for use" means, technically speaking.